# runas command in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, administration, runas

I'm trying to run a batch file as admin. I found that I can use runas command which corresponds sudo command in Linux I think.

I tried

runas /noprofile /user:computername\adminuser "blah.bat start"

But it gives an error, saying :

Logon failure: user account restriction.. (msdos window doesn't allow me to copy anything) is there any way I can run this batch file as admin? Right click doesn't work because I can't include any parameters.

Comment: To copy, click system menu (icon in title bar) find the mark menu item. (You should turn on quick edit for the console, life will be much better)

Comment: Note to add: Pretty much no black rectangle with gray text in it has been DOS for over a decade now.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround: You can create a shortcut to the batch file, add a parameter in the shortcut, then right-click to run the shortcut as admin.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the icon for the command-prompt and choose Run As Administrator.  Then run you batch file from that window.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can allow or disallow the RunAs command with the registry.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\Explorer
"HideRunAsVerb"= 1
```

See [Disabling the RunAs Command](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/kbase/WindowsTips/Windows2003/AdminTips/Admin/DisablingtheRunAsCommand.html)